# Can't do a simple data passing with an intent (Android)

Tags: java, android, xml

It displays the xml in the other activity, i mean, the intent works but my string value isn't as expected.

I only want to get the String in the other activity to fill with a color a figure in a canvas. The canvas work with local variables.

I want to get the F*cking string value of my other activity, i mean, i putted a "valor" on the intent String value, still doesnt work, don't know why.

Any help is fully appreciated, I guess the problem is in the getIntent method, or something like that.

Receiver activity

```
package com.example.escom.dbms2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;

    public class FiguraActvity extends AppCompatActivity {

public final static String KEYFIG = "colorID";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String cID = (String) bundle.get(KEYFIG);

    Figura currentFig = new Figura(this);


    currentFig.setCurrentColorID(cID);

    if (cID =="valor") {
        setContentView(currentFig);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_figura_actvity);

}



public class Figura extends View {

    String currentColorID;

    public Figura(Context c) {
        super(c);



    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);




        Rect rectangulo = new Rect();
        rectangulo.set(0,0,canvas.getWidth()/2,canvas.getHeight()/2);

        Paint currentcolor = new Paint();

        if (currentColorID =="1") {
            currentcolor.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        else if (currentColorID =="2"){
            currentcolor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        else if (currentColorID =="3"){
            currentcolor.setColor(Color.RED);
        }

        else  {
            currentcolor.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        }

        currentcolor.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRect(rectangulo,currentcolor);




    }

    public void setCurrentColorID(String ID){

        currentColorID=ID;

    }


}

    }

     package com.example.escom.dbms2;


    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.Paint;
    import android.graphics.Path;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.*;
```

Sender Activity, in the  if(v==jbnV) is the intent.

```
    public class DbmsActivity2 extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

public final static String KEYFIG = "colorID";
EditText        jetI, jetN;
Button          jbnA, jbnB, jbnC, jbnV, jbnL, jbnI, jbnF;
SQLiteDatabase  db;
String currentColorID;
String currentColorName;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dbms2);
    jetI=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.xetI);
    jetN=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.xetN);

    jbnA=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnA);   jbnA.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnB=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnB);   jbnB.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnC=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnC);   jbnC.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnV=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnV);   jbnV.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnL=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnL);   jbnL.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnI=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnI);   jbnI.setOnClickListener(this);
    jbnF=(Button)findViewById(R.id.xbnF);   jbnF.setOnClickListener(this);



    db=openOrCreateDatabase("DBColores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS colores (ID VARCHAR, nombre VARCHAR);");

    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM colores WHERE ID='" + "1" + "'");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM colores WHERE ID='" + "2" + "'");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM colores WHERE ID='" + "3" + "'");
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM colores WHERE ID='" + "4" + "'");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO colores VALUES('" + "1" + "','" + "BLACK" + "');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO colores VALUES('" + "2" + "','" + "BLUE" + "');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO colores VALUES('" + "3" + "','" + "RED" + "');");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO colores VALUES('" + "4" + "','" + "YELLOW" + "');");

}
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v==jbnA){
        if( jetI.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || jetN.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){
            mensaje("Error", "Ingresar todos los datos");
            return;
        }
        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO colores VALUES('" + jetI.getText() + "','" + jetN.getText() + "');");
        mensaje("Alta", "Registro agregado");
        limpiar();
    }
    if(v==jbnB){
        if(jetI.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){
            mensaje("Error", "Ingresar el ID");
            return;
        }
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM colores WHERE ID='" + jetI.getText() + "'", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM colores WHERE ID='" + jetI.getText() + "'");
            mensaje("Baja", "Registro eliminado");
        } else {
            mensaje("Error", "ID inválido");
        }
        limpiar();
    }
    if(v==jbnC){
        if(jetI.getText().toString().trim().length()==0) {
            mensaje("Error", "Ingresar el ID");
            return;
        }
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM colores WHERE ID='" + jetI.getText() + "'", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            db.execSQL("UPDATE colores SET nombre='" + jetN.getText()  + "' WHERE ID='" + jetI.getText() + "'");
            mensaje("Cambio", "Registro modificado");
        } else {
            mensaje("Error", "ID inválido");
        }
        limpiar();
    }
    if(v==jbnV) {
        if(jetI.getText().toString().trim().length()==0) {
            mensaje("Error", "Ingresar el ID");
            return;
        }

        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM colores WHERE ID='" + jetI.getText() + "'", null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {

           //currentColorID = jetI.getText().toString();
            currentColorID = "1";


           Intent i;
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FiguraActvity.class);


            i.putExtra(KEYFIG,"valor");


            startActivity(i);

        }
        else   {
            mensaje("Error", "ID inválido");
            limpiar();
        }
    }
    if(v==jbnL)  {
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM colores", null);
        if(c.getCount()==0){
            mensaje("Error", "No hay registros");
            return;
        }
        StringBuffer buffer=new StringBuffer();
        while(c.moveToNext())    {
            buffer.append("ID: " + c.getString(0)+"\n");
            buffer.append("Nombre: " + c.getString(1)+"\n");

        }
        mensaje("Lista", buffer.toString());
    }
    if(v==jbnI)  {
        mensaje("Examen App Development for Mobile", "ESCOM");
    }


    if(v==jbnF)  {

    startActivity(new Intent(DbmsActivity2.this, LienzoActivity.class));

    }

}
public void mensaje(String s,String m)  {
    Builder b=new Builder(this);
    b.setCancelable(true);
    b.setTitle(s);
    b.setMessage(m);
    b.show();
}
public void limpiar()    {
    jetI.setText("");
    jetN.setText("");
    jetI.requestFocus();
}






 }
```

Sender activity lines that matters

```
           currentColorID = "1";


           Intent i;
            i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FiguraActvity.class);


            i.putExtra(KEYFIG,"valor");


            startActivity(i);
```

Receiver Activity lines that matters

```
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String cID = (String) bundle.get(KEYFIG);
```

Variable that is in both activities

```
   public final static String KEYFIG = "colorID";
```

XML Manifest

http://pastebin.com/2nwpCGkC

Comment: cID =="valor" make it cID.equals("valor") . Can you verify n let me know

Comment: It do it, i dont think that is the issue.

Comment: you need to keep     setContentView(R.layout.activity_figura_actvity); in else case. posted in my answer. can you verifyo nce

Comment: any update? if you already fixed it. please post the answer to make sure we have closure on this thread.

Comment: Yup, Ramesh, you was right. It was the equals, plus the setContent view, Thanks a lot... by the way, is there a way to upvote the right answer?

Comment: good to know it fixed your issue. I am not sure about it. You can try it out and see :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you have problem with passing values. While comparing you are comparing with == but you are supposed to compare with equals.

```
if (cID.equals("valor")) {
    setContentView(currentFig);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_figura_actvity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here :

```
i.putExtra(KEYFIG,"valor");
```

as u have directly put the value as extra. But, while extracting or receiving value u are first extracting bundle and then extracting values from bundle.

So, either you put Extra values as bundle on sender side, then it will work.
Otherwise, just get extras on receiver side.

Also, 
problem may be in comparing values, as u are using "==" which is used to compare references not values. You should use equals() to compare values.

Comment: putExtra also inserts in mExtras which is a bundle. so When he says getExtras it will return the same bundle. I dont think that is a mistake.

Comment: if (cID =="valor") {
        setContentView(currentFig);
    }     // "==" is used to compare the references or memory address. equals() should be used to match the values. This may be the error.

Comment: yup thats what I had posted as an answer already!! 
putExtra is just a wrapper around handling bundle.

Comment: I already tried with putExtra(String) in the Intent and in a Bundle.

Comment: change "==" with equals and then try

Comment: I tried with equals, but is the same, it shows the second activity instead of the first one (which should show if the value is the same) Maybe I can show the value somewhere to see what is doing?

Comment: Maybe something in the XML file is wrong? Note: if i initialize a String value in the receiver, the == and equals works fine.

Comment: how are you verifying it. by keeping breakpoint ? at the end in all the cases you set     setContentView(R.layout.activity_figura_actvity);
so always your second one only show right ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is where you want to extract the value (according to its type) from the intent code should be as : 
    `String cID = getIntent().getStringExtra(KEYFIG);`

and where you want to put values in intent, it should be as 

    `i.putExtra(KEYFIG,"valor");`

I guess this will do the trick

Comment: I already tried this, I think something is wrong with the Intent or the get Intent.